# React Native - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-component

actually i'm a newbie in RN,
i have a problem, I have researched everywhere but found nothing!

I got this error when i try to navigate from a screen to another **"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')"**

this is my component and the whole project: https://github.com/saidziani/News/blob/other-articles/components/Rowstd.js

Comment: Does `this.props.navigation.navigate` work in other components? Or same issue in them as well?

Comment: Please include a minimal example to reproduce the problem, not the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass this.props.navigation from parent to component and then, you can use it.

In your case, i think you should pass this.props.navigation from Home.js to Rowstd like this:

```
<Rowstd article={row} index={parseInt(i, 10)} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

Comment: Thank you, thats was the exact solution, BTW i created (and closed) an isssue on my Github (https://github.com/saidziani/News/issues/2)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass `navigation` prop manually to every component.

Just make sure that you have added `<Rowstd />` component to your route stack.

`navigation` prop will not be available if you have not done so.

> `this.props.navigation`: the navigation prop is passed in to every screen component (definition) in stack navigator

If you want to access it from non-route screen e.g middleware ( if you are using `redux`) then you have to create a `NavigationService`.

More details here - [Navigating without navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html)